# Vmware dual monitor problem

Tags: vmware, multiple-monitors

I have a mac system which has a vmware windows system installed. Besides I have two monitors. Now I want to show windows in one monitor and mac in another monitor. I can drag the vmware to another monitor, But when I maximize the vmware, then vmware will occupy the two monitors, the mac system will disappear. Anyone know the solution for this problem ? BTW my colleague's machine do not have problem, and we have the same hardware, so I think this is a software configuration problem

Thank you in advance.

Jeff Zhang

Answer (score 1):

This may well depend on your monitor configuration. If you have the two monitors configured as a single horizontal span then maximise will maximise to both windows. If you have the monitors configured as independent, then you should be able to maximise to a single one.

For monitor configuration on OSX, open System Preferences > Displays

Comment: How to do the monitor configuration